# about getopt syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, getopt, getopts

Alright, I am a linux bash amateur playing with `getops` and `getop`; I have read several conversations in several forums regarding the topic, but I can't seem to make my code work.

Here is a little script using `getopts`, recycled from this forum:

```
#!bin/bash

while getopts ":a:p:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) arg_1="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    p) arg_2="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?)
    ;;
  esac
done

printf "Argument firstArg is %s\n" "$arg_1"
printf "Argument secondArg is %s\n" "$arg_2"
```

It does its job:

```
bash test02.sh -asomestring -bsomestring2 #either with or without quotes
#Argument firstArg is somestring
#Argument secondArg is somestring2
```

Now, since I want to try long options names, I am trying `getopt`, trying to comprehend  the syntax from examples I found online:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=`getopt -o a:b: -l arga:,argb:--"$@"`
eval set --"$temp"

while true ; do
  case "$1" in
    a|arga) firstArg="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    b|argb) secondArg="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?)
    ;;
  esac
done

printf "Argument firstArg is %s\n" "$firstArg"
printf "Argument secondArg is %s\n" "$secondArg"
```

The above code does not work:

```
bash test04.sh -a'somestring' -b'somestring2' #either with or without quotes
#getopt: invalid option -- 'b'
#Try `getopt --help' for more information.
#
bash test04.sh --arga=somestring --argb=somestring2
#getopt: unrecognized option '--argb=somestring2'
#Try `getopt --help' for more information.
```

Can you please help me understand my mistakes?

Comment: Put a space after `--` in `eval set -- "$temp"`

Comment: Also before `"$@"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried, but it still does not work; I get: "getopt: unknown shell after -s or --shell argument". I guess it's reading the "s" from the "something"  if I also put a space after argb, i.e.: arga:,argb:--"$@" , the result is that the terminal just hangs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need proper spaces before and after `--`.

```
temp=`getopt -o a:b: -l arga:,argb: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$temp"
```

And in your `while` loop that processes the result, you need to use the `shift` command to go to the next option, otherwise you'll just keep processing the same option forever.

`getopt` doesn't set variables like `$OPTARG`, you just use positional parameters.

```
while true ; do
  case "$1" in
    -a|--arga) firstArg="$2"; shift 2
    ;;
    -b|--argb) secondArg="$2"; shift 2
    ;;
    --) shift; break
    ;;
    *) echo "Bad option: $1"; shift
    ;;
  esac
done
```

See the examples at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/getopt.htm

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to help me. I did the changes, but now I get an endless printing of "Bad option:" with nothing printed out after the "option:"

Comment: You need to detect the end of options with a `--` case.

Comment: Ok, now the loop is not endless. The remaining problem is that it gives me "bad option" for both options

Comment: The cases need the `-` or `--` prefixes.

Comment: LOL, I was just doing that, adding the '-' and '--'.  Problem is now, it does not give me error anymore, but the printf variable parts are both empty, i.e.:  "Argument firstArg is" " Argument secondArg is"

Comment: `$OPTARG` should be `$2`.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work! Ahem, "we" got it to work: I changed "$OPTARG" with "$2" in both cases. It works with both short and long names

Comment: LOL, we overlapped. Thank you. And thank you for the link as well. Help mne to understad, the "$1" refers to the option name, while the "$2" refers to the option itself, am I correct? Thank you for your time and attention :)

Comment: You understand that `eval set -- "$temp"` copies `$temp` into the positional arguments, right? So `$1` is the first argument, `$2` is the second argument, and so on. Each time you use `shift 2`, it removes the first 2 arguments, so the next option becomes `$1`, and its parameter becomes `$2`.